# Yii2: Get raw sql of $query->count('*') in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to get the raw query for `$query->count("*")`.

I have tried

```
$s=$query->count("*");
$s=$s->createCommand()->sql;
```

It does not work.

Usually I do `$s=$query->createCommand()->sql;` to get raw sql which works fine. How to get it for `count('*')`. Please help.

Comment: You can't use `createCommand()` on `$s`, because `count()` method returns **`integer|string`**, it's **not an object**.

Comment: @Yupik Yes i figured. Is there a way to get the query for the count?

Comment: How about just `$query->select('count(*)')->sql`?

Comment: @Yupik Doesn't work. Tried `$a =$query->count('*')->sql` too. Doens't work either

Comment: What exacly means `doesnt work`?

Comment: @Yupik Sry bout that. It returns nothing. Both.

Comment: Are you sure you tried exacly what i've put here? Not `$query->count('*')->sql` - because, as i said before, `count()` returns integer or string. Use `$query->select('count(*)')->createCommand()->sql`. There's **`select()`** method.

Comment: @Yupik omg apologies. Retried it. It worked. Mustv'e missed something on the first try. Please put it as an answer. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `createCommand()` on `$s`, because `count()` method returns **integer|string**, it's not **an object**. To get count sql, you can use:

```
$query->select('count(*)')->createCommand()->sql
```